# primefaces keyfilter regular expression

Tags: regex, primefaces, keyfilter

I got a problem regarding to the keyfilter from primefaces extension.
I want to define a regular expression for a time period for example "P1Y3M2W1d".
The following regular expression for the key filter is used:

```
<pe:keyFilter regEx="/P[0-9]*Y*[0-9]*M*[0-9]*W*[0-9]*d*/" />
```

The goal is that user might only type in **P** first then digit number 0-9, afterwards Y(year), M(Month) or W(Week) and so on. The problem is I can only type in captial P and nothing else. I check the regular expression. It is correct. What is the problem with regular expression in keyFilter?
Thanks for help!!!

Update:

```
<p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="period" >
   <pe:keyFilter regEx="/P([0-9]+Y)?([0-9]+M)?([0-9]+W)?([0-9]+d)?/" />
</p:inputText>
```

I think primefaces extension uses the jquery keyfilter plugin. The regEx should be quoted around "//", but somehow the only possibility in my UI is to captial P

Comment: What's acceptable after the `P`? Do the other portions (Y, M, W, d) have to be provided or are they optional? Your current regex will most certainly accept the input string `P` because you've used the `*` quantifier on all of the other portions.

Comment: the acceptable after the P is number such as 0-9. The other portions (Y,M,W,d) is optional, but you need to type in at least one char such as P3Y or P3M.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using regex with p:keyFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-pkeyfilter)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
regEx="/P([0-9]+Y)?([0-9]+M)?([0-9]+W)?([0-9]+d)?/"
```

Comment: That regular expression is correct but somehow doesn't works for the key filter. I can only type in captial P

Comment: @user1063808 What do you mean when you say you can only type P? What happens when you type the next character? Is this filter interactive or static?

Comment: Yes, In the UI, I can only type in captial P, the other Char is forbidden. Strange!!!

Comment: @user1063808 So, based on that, you concluded the filter is responsible for blocking your input? Run a simple test, change the filter to **"/.*/"**, it should accept any string of characters. If you are still blocked after the first character, the problem lies somwhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I try /.*/. It doesn't block any Char, but the thing is I want to define the first Char is captial P.

Comment: @user1063808 Only one other thing comes to mind. There is an option in regular expressions called "greedy", which should be by default ON. Greedy means "take the **longest** possible input". If for some reason, in your system, greedy is OFF, then it will do the opposite "take the **shortest** possible input", and for your regular expression the shortest is "P", and then maybe because of this it takes "P" to be the final result.