# Using regex with p:keyFilter

Tags: regex, jsf, primefaces

I have an `p:inputMask` with a `p:keyFilter` to match time in the `HH:mm` pattern as following:

```html
<p:inputMask mask="99:99" ...>
     <p:keyFilter regEx="([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"/>
</p:inputMask>
```

But it doesn't work and it accepts all values from `00:00` to `99:99`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `regEx="/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn't work :/ my regex works when I test it on https://regex101.com/ but for some reason the inputMask doesn't filter the input

Comment: And what if you use `<p:keyFilter regEx="/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/" />`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I get this error : '<p:keyFilter> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: keyFilter'

Comment: Try also removing `mask="99:99"`. It might override the regex check. And use `<pe:keyFilter regEx="/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/" />`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I already did that I even used inputText instead of inputMask but unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: You mean you tried without the `mask` attribute?

Answer (score 13):

### `p:keyFilter` versus `f:validateRegex` – `regEx` versus `inputRegEx`

`p:keyFilter` with the `regEx` attribute is used to filter characters (on each key stroke), it does not allow you to validate an expression (on the complete inputted value). If you want to validate if your input matches a regular expression, use the `inputRegEx` attribute or `f:validateRegex`.

So, in your case you could use:

```html
<p:inputXxx ...>
    <f:validateRegex pattern="([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"/>
</p:inputXxx>
```

Please note that `p:keyFilter` requires JavaScript regular expressions, while, while `f:validateRegex` requires a Java regular expression. And, `p:keyFilter inputRegEx` is checked on key up, while `f:validateRegex` is executed when the field is processed. The proper way to use `p:keyFilter` would be:

```html
<p:inputXxx ...>
    <p:keyFilter inputRegEx="/[0-9:]/"/>
</p:inputXxx>
```

But that will still allow invalid input.

So, in resume:

| Property | `p:keyFilter inputRegEx="..."` | `f:validateRegex pattern="..."` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Regular expression type | JavaScript | Java |
| Executed when | Key up JavaScript event is triggered | Component is processed |

This applies to all text input components (like `p:inputText`), so not only to the `p:inputMask` you are using).

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/keyfilter
- [Convert Javascript regular expression to Java syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754444/convert-javascript-regular-expression-to-java-syntax/52925590)

### Before PrimeFaces 6

Note that `p:keyFilter` is available since 6.0. For older versions you need PrimeFaces Extensions `pe:keyFilter`. Note that versions of PFE before 6.0 do not align with PF versions.

### For something completely different

You could simply use `p:datePicker`, which nowadays can be used to enter time (hours and minutes) only:

```html
<p:datePicker pattern="HH:mm" .../>
```

Or you could have a look at [`pe:timePicker`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timePicker/basicUsage.jsf).

Comment: Thanks that was useful but I really want to filter the user input to match my regex

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent the user from typing anything that doesn't match the regex, unless he types something that match it.