# How can I make the area code optional with p:inputMask

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to implement a primefaces inputMask for a phone number using the example in the showcase.

```
<p:inputMask id="phone" value="#{identity.phone}" mask="(999) 999-9999? x9999"/>
```

I need to change it to allow the area code and/or the extension to be optional. If I move the ? to the beginning to make everything optional, it populates the field like this: (123)-111-1.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The `mask` of the `p:inputMask` is not a regular expression. If it would be, it would be very confusing to the user.

So, just let users always the area code in the `p:inputMask`, or convert it to a plain `p:inputText` and add a `f:validateRegex` validator to check if the phone number is valid (with optional area code), or use two fields (one for the area code and one for the phone number) and add add custom validation. In the last case OmniFaces [`o:validateMultiple`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple) might be worth checking out.

See also:

- [Using regex with inputMask in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-inputmask-in-primefaces)