# InputMask and regex for colon separated numbers in primefaces

Tags: jsf

I have a column in datatable where user can enter colon separated numbers in the following format:
     0:0:0:0 to 32767:65535:65535:65535

I have tried the following 2 approaches but they don't seem to work correctly or look nice:

```
  <p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{myClass.col1}" /></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
       <p:inputMask mask="9?9999:9?9999:9?9999:9?9999" maxlength="23" value="#{myClass.col1}" >
       </p:inputMask>
    </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
```

I also tried:

```
  <p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{myClass.col1}" /></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
       <p:inputText value="#{myClass.col1}" >
          <f:validateRegex pattern="^([0-9]{0,5}[:-]){3}([0-9]{0,5})"/>
       </p:inputText>
    </f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
```

Is there anyway I can combine inputMask and validateRegex so that the "blank" (initial) cell looks like "    :    :    :    ", the accepted range is 0:0:0:0 to 32767:65535:65535:65535 and also the values entered are right justified (i.e "   1:  23: 345:4567")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regex with inputMask in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-inputmask-in-primefaces)

Comment: Based on this, I now have 

`<p:inputMask mask=" " maxlength="23" value="#{myClass.col1}" >
       <f:validateRegex pattern=" "/>
 </p:inputMask>`

What will be the mask for "1 to 5 digits:1 to 5 digits:1 to 5 digits:1 to 5 digits" ?
What will be the regex pattern for "0:0:0:0 to 32767:65535:65535:65535"?

Comment: In your case I would throw in a custom validator to handle the ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to come up with the following reqex pattern for validating values between 0:0:0:0 to 32767:65535:65535:65535:

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^((3276[0-7]?|327[0-5]?[0-9]?|32[0-6]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|3[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[012]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)((\:)(6553[0-5]?|655[012]?[0-9]?|65[0-4]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|6[0-4]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9])){3})"/>
```

Comment: Custom validator would have been easier to creatie and eadier to understand by others imo. But great it works