# KeyFilter Regex - Stop Characters' Input After Seqeuence

Tags: jquery, primefaces, keyfilter

I am using [primefaces's p:keyFilter](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml) tag to filter the key. Primefaces apparently using [jQuery KeyFilter](https://github.com/akzhan/jquery-keyfilter). I am trying to achieve

> 0 or many times `\d` can be entered but if user type "," then maximum only
>   2 digits are allowed. Also Only one time user can use ",". Ex: 2334,2 or 232,33 or ,34 etc

For this I come up with `/^(\d)*(,\d{1,2})?$/` regex. It works fine with backend java validation, but when I try to use it within `<p:keyFilter>` it seems not working.

I tried many solutions, one of them is `/[\d,\d{1,2}?]/` but user can enter multiple times "," and more then 2 digits after ",". It seems like `p:keyFilter` cannot solve my problem.

I want to get the latest key entered that changed the inputtext and if not valid (according to regex), then stop/remove the entered key. I think this functionality cannot be implemented using f:validateRegex with ajax.

Does anyone know how can I filter the keys while input in a way that I am looking for ?

I am using primefaces 6.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regex with inputMask in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-inputmask-in-primefaces)

Comment: @JasperdeVries, my question is quite different from the one that you are referring.

Comment: Did you read the answer as well?

Comment: Yes I already checked the solution. I am already using `f:validateRegex `, but the problem is that it only validate at on form submission.

Comment: Well, yes. You could use Ajax though.

Comment: Right. But I want to get the latest key entered that changed the inputtext and if not valid (according to regex), then stop/remove the entered key. I think this functionality cannot be implemented using `f:validateRegex ` with ajax. Hope you get my point.

Comment: Why not? Anyhow, I personally would not use Ajax for this (and safe roundtrips to the server) and go for something like https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask