# Looking for a Regex for only a certain type of chars and no duplication

Tags: java, regex, primefaces, keyfilter

I am looking for a regex only for certain chars and no duplications. I have to write an app for a restaurant and they want to write the allergens of the food (ABCDEFGHLMNOPR). Therefore only those chars should be allowed without duplications.

I am using primefaces and I tried a lot of different regex before. They worked on https://regex101.com/r/dVohnx/1 but sadly not in the app.

//this regEx works on regex101 online editor but not for me.

```
<p:inputText id="id" value="#{allergene}" disabled="#{!speiseplanView.editable and hasEditPermission}">
   <p:keyFilter regEx="/^(?:([ABCDEFGHLMNOPR])(?!\1))+$/" />
</p:inputText>
```

The problem is, I only limited the chars with that code but not the duplication.

thank you, guys!

Comment: If a negative lookahead is supported, you might try `([ABCDEFGHLMNOPR])(?!.*\1)` to get the matches without the duplicates https://regex101.com/r/EDsLuJ/1

Comment: first of all thx for the fast answer. sadly this doesnt work too. it only reduces the possible chars but I can write for example: "AAAABBBB" but the output should only be "AB"

Comment: From what I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-pkeyfilter) is that keyFilter is used to filter characters (on each key stroke). Would the other suggested `<f:validateRegex` help you?

Comment: Sounds good, I tried it but now the regex doesnt match in any ways.

Comment: I replaced the keyFilter with: <f:validateRegex pattern="^(?:([ABCDEFGHLMNOPR])(?!\1))+$" />

Comment: And if you try `([ABCDEFGHLMNOPR])(?!.*\1)` without the anchors.

Comment: ok, it works but only after pressing the trigger button. I wanted it the "keyFilter" way and that it checks the input per every key stroke.

Comment: Ok, I will make an mix of both and I am using:

Comment: <p:keyFilter regEx="/[ABCDEFGHLMNOPR]/" />
           <f:validateRegex pattern="/^(?:([ABCDEFGHLMNOPR])(?!\1))+$/"/>

Comment: The only knowledge of primefaces itself I got from the posting I read. Does that work for you?

Comment: yes, thx. now it works. but I have a problem with my statement. it allows strings like this: "AEBCE" but the E is already inside.

Comment: The pattern matches only the chars, so for `AEBCE` the matches are `ABCE`. You might get the unique characters and compare that with the original string. Is there no other way to deduplicate the chars and compare them with the original string?