# Primefaces keyFilter doesn't match all values defined in regex

Tags: regex, jsf, primefaces, keyfilter

I'm trying to restrict input with Primefaces `keyFilter` to match all numbers from 1 to 99 using regex. This is what I have at the moment:

```
<p:inputText id="inNum" maxlength="2">
    <p:keyFilter regEx="/^[1-9][0-9]?$/" preventPaste="true" />
</p:inputText>
```

Input accepts the majority of desired number except those that have 0 as a second digit (10, 20, 30,..).

I can't figure it out why is that so. I've also tested that regular expression with online testers and it seems to be ok.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It just means you can only check a single keystoke with the regex, and since it requires a non-zero digit as the first char, it only will allow a digit from 1 to 9. You need to check the whole input value with the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I already thought about that, so i tried with `inputRegEx` attribute. The documentation for `inputRegEx` states: _Defines the regular expression which should be used to test the complete input text content._ It seems that this way I can enter 10, 20, 30... but there's another problem. Once I enter e.g. 10 and then I try to clear the input, first digit (1 in my case) cannot be cleared. Don't know why but it's not the behavior that I want.

Comment: Yes, then you need to make them both (sequentially) optional. Try `inputRegEx='/^(?:[1-9][0-9]?)?$/'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's exactly I was looking for, thank you very much. Feel free to post your solution as an answer to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using regex with p:keyFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083226/using-regex-with-pkeyfilter)

Comment: @JasperdeVries yes, it partially does, I realized that I should use inputRegEx attribute. Wiktor's answer finnaly solve my problem with input restriction - also my regular expression was incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regEx` attribute only checks a single keystoke with its regex, and since the `^[1-9][0-9]?$` pattern requires a non-zero digit as the first character, it only will allow a digit from 1 to 9. You need to check the whole input value with the `inputRegEx` attribute.

You can use

```
inputRegEx='/^(?:[1-9][0-9]?)?$/'
```

Since you are using a regex for live validation input, you need to make sure that even an empty string passes the check, so all the subpatterns must be optional, and since you only allow non-zero digit at the start, the subpatterns must be sequentially optional.

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[1-9][0-9]?)?`  - an optional sequence of

  - `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
  - `[0-9]?` - an optional digit
- `$` - end of string.